# js trigonometry centering after rotation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, math, css

[image: Here's the scenario]

Oh ye javascript gods!
One for those who still remember trigonometry from school ;-)

See the link below, I'm essentially trying to center some content however the normal screenwidth-divwidth/2 style equation isn't working because of the angles.

*only in firefox right now*
http://jsbin.com/uruvub/2/

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

First imagine a "red coordinate system" attached to the top left corner of you red box, with red y-axix given by the top border of the red box and going right, and the red y-axis given by left border of the red box and going down. The displacement `(d_x, d_y)` of the grey box in this red coordinate system is:

```
d_x = (W - w) / 2,   W = width of red box, w = width of grey box
d_y = (H - h) / 2,   H = height of red box, h = height of grey box
```

The same displacement vector `(d_x, d_y)` is valid for the top right corner of the green box.

Now, we need to express this vector `(d_x, d_y)` in the "black coordinate system" given by your X-axis and Y-axis. The red system system can be transformed into the black system by the rotation by the angle `a` (your designated angle) and a shift of the origin. The rotated vector is

```
D_x = d_x * cos(a) - d_y * sin(a)
D_y = d_x * sin(a) + d_y * cos(a)
```

This is the displacement in the black system with respect to the top left corner of the red box expressed in the black system.

Remark: Perhaps you need to change `a` to `-a` in the above formula depending on the sense of the rotation.

Comment: hey thanks so much for the response, this didn;t fix it but after a bit of reading here, i was able to do it via trig.:http://www.jjgifford.com/expressions/geometry/trigonometry.html